# Need tips with using an IF statement, while ignoring blank cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need help with an IF statement where I want Excel (2021) to ignore blank cells in the calculation.

- Column A:  Dates of Birth (formatted as dates, contains some blanks)
- Column B:  Date of Incident (formatted as dates, no blanks)
- Column C:  Calculated Age at Time of Incident (formatted as a number, DateDif between DOB and Date of Incident, contains some blanks because there are some blank date of birth fields in Column A)
- Column D:  IF age (column C, which could contain some blanks) is less than 17, "Y".  If not less than 17, "N".

The specific problem is when there are blanks in Column C.   If column C is blank, I don't want any value in Column D.

In this case, there is no way around the blank date of birth fields.  I was able to create a formula for Column C to leave blank if the date of birth was blank.

But, I haven't been able to write a formula to leave Column D blank if Column C is blank AND still calculate if less than 17 years of age.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `=IF(C2="","",IF(C2<17,"Y","N"))`

Comment: That's it!!!!  And I swear I tried that variation before but think I was adding in extra parenthesis.  The "and" variation is what gave me "true", "false", which was sort of OK, but not what I wanted.  Thank you so much, Scott!